# Динамическая работа с компонентами на форме

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Допустим, есть N форм, на каждой форме N textBox, которые нужно проверить на пустоту.

Можно ли это сделать динамически или для каждой формы придется писать свою функцию проверки компонентов с явным их перечислением?

Т.е некоторая функция, которой подается массив имен элементов и каждый этот компонент проверяется на пустоту.

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам универсальный метод проверки, есть ли где-либо на форме пустой текстбокс. Список имен можете прикрутить сами.

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static bool HasEmptyTextBox(this Form form)
    {
        if (form == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("form");
        }
        return ControlHasEmptyTextBox(form);
    }

    private static bool ControlHasEmptyTextBox(Control control)
    {
        // проверяем текстбоксы
        foreach (var textBox in control.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // проверяем контролы-контейнеры
        foreach (var child in control.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => c.HasChildren))
        {
            if (ControlHasEmptyTextBox(child))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Когда я вижу Allman со скобками вокруг return, мне хочется вырвать себе глаза. Отвлекаясь от форматирования, я бы отделил рекурсивное перечисление контролов от проверки, тогда можно будет заменять проверку без копипасты всего этого безобразия.

Answer (score 2):

Решение как у **@andreycha**, только в более общем виде и более полное.

У контролов есть свойство `Control.Controls`, которое содержит дочерние контролы. Чтобы пройтись по всем, нужно рекурсивно пройтись по иерархии. После этого фильтрация последовательности, проверка свойств и прочее становятся тривиальными однострочными LINQ-запросами.

```
public static class ControlExts
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this Control @this) =>
        IterateChildren(@this).Skip(1);

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllChildren<T>(this Control @this) =>
        @this.GetAllChildren().OfType<T>();

    public static bool IsAnyTextBoxEmpty(this Control @this) =>
        @this.GetAllChildren<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text));

    private static IEnumerable<Control> IterateChildren(this Control @this)
    {
        if (@this == null)
            yield break;
        yield return @this;
        foreach (Control child in @this.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(IterateChildren))
            yield return child;
    }
}
```

Теперь вы можете делать вот так, например:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (TextBox box in this.GetAllChildren<TextBox>())
            box.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
        textBox_TextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = this.IsAnyTextBoxEmpty() ? "Empty" : "Filled";
    }
}
```